# How to access code in a top-level file in a python package

Tags: python, package

I have a Python 2.7 package laid out like this:

```
hdl/
    __init__.py
    run_job.py
    other_stuff/
        __init__.py
        other_files/
setup.py
scripts/
    client.py
```

`run_job.py` contains:

```
def run_job():
    pass
```

There is no class. Actually, there are no classes anywhere in this codebase; I inherited it.

How do I execute the `run_job()` function from clients of this package?

(Right now, the run_job() function lives in `__init__.py`, which I don't like at all.)

I put these in `__init__.py`:

```
import hdl.run_job

import run_job
```

Either way, I get `No module named run_job`. If I leave off the import entirely, the client code says either `'module' object has no attribute 'run_job'` or `name 'run_job' is not defined`, depending on which of these I do:

```
import hdl
hdl.run_job

import hdl
run_job
```

My `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import find_packages
from os import walk, path

install_requires = [
    "ecdsa==0.11",
    "importlib==1.0.3",
    "paramiko==1.13.0",
    "pyasn1==0.1.7",
    "pycrypto==2.6.1",
    "wsgiref==0.1.2",
]

script_base = "scripts"
my_path = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))
walk_path = path.join(my_path, script_base)
for(_, _, filenames) in walk(walk_path):
    scripts = [("%s/%s"  % (script_base, f)) for f in filenames]
    break

setup(
    name="hdl",
    version="dev",
    description="HDL",
    url="http://example.com",
    long_description="HDLA",
    author="heh",
    author_email=".com",
    maintainer="foo",
    maintainer_email=".com",
    license="Proprietary",
    packages=find_packages(exclude=("tests",)),
    test_suite="nose.collector",
    include_package_data=True,
    package_data = {'': [ '*.csv', '*.hql', '*.pig', '*.sh', '*.sql' ]},
    install_requires=install_requires,
    zip_safe=False,
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 2 - Alpha",
        "Environment :: Command Line",
        "Framework :: None",
        "Intended Audience :: Developers",
        "Intended Audience :: System Administrators",
        "License :: Other/Proprietary License",
        "Natural Language :: English",
        "Operating System :: MacOS :: MacOS X",
        "Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7",
        "Topic :: Software Development",
        "Topic :: ETL"
    ],
    scripts=scripts,
)
```

If I stick the `run_job` function in `__init__.py` it works fine:
    import hdl
    hdl.run_job()

Comment: ``from hdl import run_job``

Comment: Says `cannot import name run_job'

Comment: which __init__.py are you editing? The one in hd1 or other_stuff?

Comment: The one in `hdl`. The one in `other_stuff` is irrelevant, and if its relevant then there's something *very* weird about Python.

Comment: What do you mean by "clients of this package"?  You mean programs that import `hdl`?  Have you tried using `import hdl.run_job` inside the *client* code?

Comment: clients = programs that import `hdl`. I just tried `import hdl.run_job` from the client code, and that led to `No module named run_job`

Comment: @Satya: Might need to debug this in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python).

Comment: I'm in chat. But I'm also sleepy, and this is getting annoying. This code should have been written right to begin with. I've struggled with this long enough - I'm only still at it because I'd like to know the right way to do this. But I'm at the end of my rope, I doubt anyone else cares, so I'll just shove the code back into __init__ and go to bed, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following in `__init__.py`:

```
__all__ = ["run_job"]
```

In your client:

```
from hdl import run_job
run_job.run_job()
```

in your setup.py "scripts" variable is not defined, so I had to remove the following string:

scripts=scripts,

After that I ran "sudo python setup.py install" and tested it with the client:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 17:40:27) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from hdl import run_job
>>> run_job.run_job()
>>>
```

Everything works.
Try yet another thing:

```
pydoc hdl
```

Check if the path provided in the generated doc refers to the right location.

```
Help on package hdl:

NAME
    hdl

FILE
    <path-to-hdl>/hdl/__init__.py

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    run_job
```

So, I have exactly the same layout and setup.py file as yours. Below is the content of files and it works on my comp. Try to carefully compare with what you have and make sure that "setup.py install" doesn't have any errors. If pydoc doesn't show anything, hdl was not installed.

```
==========
run_job.py
=========== 
def run_job():
    pass
```

============
   client.py
   ===========

```
from hdl import run_job
run_job.run_job()
```

============
   setup.py
   ===========

exactly as yours

Comment: The `__all__` is not necessary and may cause confusion later if he tries to add other things to `__init__.py`.

Comment: If he has more modules under hd1 and wants to use "from hd1 import *", he'll need __all__. It's just a common pattern for exportable modules and I'm not sure why it's confusing.

Comment: `cannot import name run_job` in the client code's import line

Comment: I stay corrected, but I think, it's still a good pattern to explicitly control what you want to export and I still don't understand why you're saying that it's confusing.

Comment: @Satya - you need to publish your setup.py script then

Comment: @OlegGryb: You're right, this is a use of `__all__` for packages, but that's why it's confusing (because `__all__` means something different for modules).  The better way to explicitly control imports within a package is to explicitly import the submodules that you want to be available with `import *`.

Comment: @Satya - just like Bren said, it works on my comp as well. You might have something non-standard in setup.py or hd1 is defined somewhere else. Probably you didn't run "python setup.py install" after you've updated your code?

Comment: I have been running `python setup.py install` after every change, its possible I missed it at some point. Something non-standard is quite possible, of course.

Comment: @Satya - it would be good to see your setup.py for further troubleshooting

Comment: Yes, just posted the setup.py

Comment: see the update - everything works except - I had to remove "scripts", which were not defined in setup.py

Comment: `scripts` is defined: `scripts = [("%s/%s"  % (script_base, f)) for f in filenames]`. `pydoc hdl` says `no Python documentation fond for 'hdl'`

Comment: are you sure that "python setup.py install" has completed successfully and there was no any errors?

Comment: Yes. It was a bad filename, sorry to waste your time. It works now.

Answer (score 3):

Your client code needs to do `from hdl import run_job` and then do `run_job.run_job()`, or (probably more readable) `from hdl.run_job import run_job`.

If you want to provide "top level" access to `run_job` (that is, not require users to import the `run_job` module to get the `run_job` function), then in your top-level `__init__.py` do `from .run_job import run_job`.  Then clients can do `import hdl` and later use `hdl.run_job`.

Comment: Says `cannot import name run_job`, and in your 2nd suggestion, `No module named run_job` (on the `from .run_job import run_job` line)

Comment: @Satya: It works for me using the file layout you've described.  Check that your files are where you think they are and are named what you think they are.  Is is possible you have another file names `hdl.py` somewhere else that is being imported instead of your package?

Comment: I'm installing them to the virtualenv by using `python setup.py install`, is that correct? The package directory structure is as I stated in my question. I don't have another hdl.py, as my changes are resulting in slightly different error messages as I go along.

Comment: @Satya: What is the name of the "client code" file from which you are trying the imports, and where is it located?

Comment: It is outside the package hierarchy. It is in the `scripts` directory and is called `client.py` (question updated after I post this comment). Since it is in `scripts`, I am running it as: `source virtualenv/bin/activate && client.py` (the `source && ` is in my history and I've been hitting up-arrow)

Answer (score 0):

The file wasn't named `run_job.py` it was named something else. *Sigh*. Fixing the name causes everything to work.

The other answers are correct; leave the `__init__.py` empty and in `client.py` do this:

```
from hdl import run_job
run_job.run_job()
```

or

```
from hdl.run_job import run_job
run_job()
```

or put this in `__init__.py`:

```
from .run_job import run_job
```

and this in `client.py`:

```
import hdl
hdl.run_job() # won't work
```

Comment: OK, I'm glad that the mystery is solved - don't forget to vote :)